# Circular graph construction to minimize overlaps

Tags: graphs-and-networks, intersection

I wish to create a set of circular graphs with 23 vertices.  An example is shown below:
[image: Circular graph]

This may be constructed by taking, for example, a random sample of the range:

```
RandomSample[Range[23]]
```

And constructing the edges from each to the next (of course wrapping at the end to form the circular graph).

Here is a second circular graph:
[image: Second circular graph]

What I mean by overlaps is that these two graphs share these edges:

```
{8 \[DirectedEdge] 14, 12 \[DirectedEdge] 16, 16 \[DirectedEdge] 22}
```

While there are three edges that overlap, the maximum length of the overlap is only 1 for this case.

I wish to construct a set of such graphs with the same numbered vertices such that they have the minimal overlap.  Overlap is defined as the maximal path length among a common set of edges.

The goal of the set is that no pair-wise elements share the same edge but I believe this is impossible for any set larger than 22.

```
anExampleSet = 
  Table[DirectedEdge @@ # & /@ 
    Transpose[{Range[23], RotateRight[Range[23], i]}], {i, 1, 22}];
```

To find the intersections, I'm using this:

```
GraphEdgeIntersections[edgePairs_List] := 
  With[{intersection = Intersection @@ edgePairs},
   If[intersection == {}, 0, 
    Max@Flatten[GraphDistanceMatrix[intersection] /. Infinity -> 0]]
   ];
```

I now construct the pairwise intersection by doing this:

```
intersectionMatrix = 
 Partition[GraphEdgeIntersections[#] & /@ Tuples[anExampleSet, 2], 22];
MatrixForm[intersectionMatrix]
(*
{{22, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0}, {0, 22, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0}, {0, 0, 22, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 22, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 22, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 22, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 22, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 22, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 22, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 22, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 22, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 22, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 22, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 22, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  22, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 22, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 22, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 22, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 22, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 22, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 22, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 22}}
*)
```

This is great as it shows that there is no intersection between pairs of these tables (other than with itself).

There is an obvious "dual" of what is written by reversing the direction of the edges.

```
anotherExampleSet = 
  Table[DirectedEdge @@ Transpose[#] & /@ 
    Transpose[{Range[23], RotateRight[Range[23], i]}], {i, 1, 22}];
```

It has the same "goodness" of having no pair-wise overlaps.  If I join these two sets and look at the intersection, I don't get the desired "zero everywhere except the diagonal".

```
Partition[
 GraphEdgeIntersections[#] & /@ 
  Tuples[Join[anotherExampleSet, anExampleSet], 2], 44]
```

Is there a construction method similar to the set that gives 22 that will allow a larger set that has the "zero everywhere except the diagonal"?

I am convincing myself that no such set larger than 22 exits.

I believe that the set of edges is given by this (self connections are excluded)

```
allPossibleEdges = 
  DirectedEdge @@ # & /@ 
   Select[Tuples[Range[23], 2], #[[1]] != #[[2]] &];
Length[%]
(*506*)
Graph[allPossibleEdges]
```

[image: Graph of all possible edges]

If I look at all edge possibilities represented by the set of 22, I get this:

```
Length[DeleteDuplicates[Flatten[anExampleSet]]]
(*506*)
```

So it seems that this set does in fact have every possible edge and it isn't possible to find a larger set since doing so requires using one of the already taken edges.

I think my new goal is to find a larger set with the minimum number of overlaps.  So, allow an overlap of 1 and see how many can now be generated.

I think the total number of possibilities is the same as choosing a subset r from a list n where in this case n=23 and r=23.  I think the possible sets is 23 factorial but finding a small subset that has the smallest pair-wise intersection is eluding me.

Update:
I wanted a way to visualize the "goodness" of the choice of graphs.  While other methods might be easier, I decided to use "Image" to show this.

Here is a generator for a set of random circular graphs:

```
someRandomGraphs = 
  With[{randomSample = #}, 
     DirectedEdge @@ # & /@ 
      Partition[Append[randomSample, randomSample[[1]]], 2, 1]] & /@ 
   Table[RandomSample[Range[23]], {i, 1, 256}];
```

I'm sure someone knows a more elegant way of getting the rules I want for my image.  I used this:

```
ConstructReplacementRule[values_, blackValue_, threshold_, 
   redNotGreen_] := 
  Block[{white = {1, 1, 1}, black = {0, 0, 0}, red = {1, 0, 0}, 
    green = {0, 1, 0}, replacementValues},
   replacementValues = 
    Cases[values, 
     a_ :> 
      If[a == blackValue, black, 
       If[redNotGreen, If[a > threshold, red, white], 
        If[a < threshold, green, white]]]];
   Thread[values -> replacementValues]
   ];
```

Now I can generate a "goodness" graph on this random set.

Let's do it for a random set:

```
gei = Partition[
   GraphEdgeIntersections[#] & /@ Tuples[someRandomGraphs, 2], 256];
```

If you run the code, you'll get a different random set - here is what I got for the case of goodness being either 0 or 1 overlap:

```
Image[gei /. 
  ConstructReplacementRule[DeleteDuplicates@Flatten@gei, 22, 2, 
   False]]
```

[image: 0 or 1 overlap]

And if I restrict to only 0 overlaps, I get this:

```
Image[gei /. 
  ConstructReplacementRule[DeleteDuplicates@Flatten@gei, 22, 1, 
   False]]
```

[image: All combinations with zero overlaps]

I can show "bad" combinations using this

```
Image[gei /. 
  ConstructReplacementRule[DeleteDuplicates@Flatten@gei, 22, 1, True]]
```

This is the "dual" of the first green curve:
[image: Showing all combinations greater than 1]

Back to the original, I would consider a "perfect" set one in which there are no red pixels in the graph that shows the intersection among pair-wise elements.  Acceptable is where there are no red pixels when I restrict to {0,1} for the maximal overlap.

Comment: Before jumping into code, can you clarify the meaning of "circular graph" and "no pair-wise elements share the same edge"?

Comment: Thanks for asking - I'll answer here and also change the description to make it more clear.  By circular I mean that the graph forms a cycle with 23 vertices.  By overlap I mean that if I take two of the graphs and align them to a single vertex, any vertex, how many common paths do they form.